# How to test multiple Web Service URL's at once in Loadrunner

Tags: automated-tests, load-testing, loadrunner

I am using HP Loadrunner to load test multiple REST Service URL's. I know how to run the tests consecutively hitting each URL but how do you run them concurrently all at once?

Comment: Note* I'm using version 11.52

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, hitting stuff simultaneously is the main use case of LoadRunner so you should be able to find everything you need in the tutorial that comes with the product and the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hit all the url simultaneously you will have to parametrize the url sequentially and set up the users in the controller to start simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

"all at once?"

Covered in training.  This type of simultaneity does not happen with a (human) user population ungoverned by a clock tick.